# Trying to use Applescript variable in curl command inside do shell script

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

this is my first post so I'm hoping someone much smarter than myself can help me out.

Trying to use an applescript variable in the curl command that is inside do shell script.  If I put "123456" in the command works just fine but using an applescript variable causes the the command to break when it reaches the pipe.

```
set theUDID to "123456"

set theSerial to do shell script "curl -sk https://something/api/udid/" & theUDID | xmllint --format - | awk -F'>|<' '/<serial_number>/{print $3}'"
```

I'm guessing it is a formatting or syntax issue but maybe I'm going about it all wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Gave that a go and received the same response.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from the variable theUDID. Then add the.. Quoted form of

Comment: Tried that and got "Can’t make quoted form of 123456 into type Unicode text."  Thank you for the thought.

Comment: Sorry, in the guidelines it says not to reply to say thank you, which I was doing. This does solve the issue and you deserve the credit.  By the way Thank You so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `theUDID` **AppleScript** *variable* as a `shell` *variable* too.

1. Leave `set theUDID to "123456"` as is.
2. Use this new `do shell script` *command*:

   ```
   set theSerial to do shell script "theUDID=" & quoted form of theUDID & "; curl -sk https://something/api/udid/$theUDID | xmllint --format - | awk -F'>|<' '/<serial_number>/{print $3}'"
   ```

This sets the **AppleScript** *variable* `theUDID` as a `shell` *variable* too, and then gets it from the `shell` at the end of the **URL** as `$theUDID`.

Comment: This answer is an excellent find. Thank you.